# Is Command spell a charm?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

Is the 1st level Command spell [PHB p223] a "charm" (that would trigger an elf's Fey Ancestry [PHB p23] racial ability and thus get advantage on the saving throw)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, *Command* isn't a charm and wouldn't trigger *Fey Ancestry.***

Spells themselves aren't classified as charms under any technical game term. They are categorized by the eight schools of magic found on page 203 of the PHB.

*Fey Ancestry* and (almost) anything that mentions being *Charmed* is referring to the charmed **condition** found on page 290 of the PHB.

As such, *Fey Ancestry* would only come into effect when a spell specifically mentions that its target is being charmed, thus imposing the *Charmed* condition.
An example of such a spell would be *Dominate Person:*

> You attempt to beguile a humanoid that you can see within range. It must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be **charmed** by you for the duration. (PHB pg.235)

Whereas *Command* doesn't mention anything about the target being charmed, it just says:

> The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn.

Comment: Also note that spells like *suggestion*, which don't apply the charmed condition but special charm defenses still apply will specify so in the spell description: "Creatures that can't be charmed are immune to this effect."